# How would I write an if-statement in continuation passing style without an if-statement?

Tags: continuations

Using continuation passing style, many common language constructs can be written in a simple language with recursion, including loops (using trampolining), exceptions, generators and even function returns. I have found numerous examples of other language constructs, but all examples I have seen use if-statements directly. Noting the power of CPS, I got curious: Can one write an if-statement in CPS without using an if-statement directly?

The naive attempt would be something along these lines:

```
if_cps(condition, true_body, false_body, current_continuation)
{
    if(condition) true_body(current_continuation);
    else false_body(current_continuation);
}
```

but obviously this is a failure, since I used an if-statement directly.

Comment: The question might be thought of as a programming question, however I am more looking for an answer _in principle_ rather than looking to actually write code in CPS. I have seen from your comment and the answer from @Derek-Elkins, that I might need to clarify my question a bit. I will try to do so.

Comment: Do you know how to encode booleans and the conditional statement in pure $\lambda$-calculus? Like this: `true = λ x y . x`, `false = λ x y . y`, `if_statement = λ condition then_body else_body . condition then_body else_body`. If you now CPS transform these, you should get an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so following the advice given by @Andrej Bauer (in the comments to my question) and @Derek Elkins (in his answer), it seems that we can actually do if-statements in CPS!

I will attempt to write out the suggested answer:

The idea is to do booleans in pure Lambda calculus, e.g. using Church encoding. The CPS version would be like this:

```
true(a, b, continuation)
{
    a(continuation);
}

false(a, b, continuation)
{
    b(continuation);
}

if_cps(condition, true_body, false_body, current_continuation)
{
     condition(true_body, false_body, current_continuation);
}
```

To use `if_cps`, we would do like this:

1. Make a closure that captures the variables needed and assign it to `true_body`
2. Make a closure that captures the variables needed and assign it to `false_body`
3. Assign one of the `true` or `false` functions to `condition`
4. Call `if_cps` with the parameters above as well as the continuation.

The `true_body` and `false_body` closures need to be arity one functions, taking the continuation as a parameter.

Comment: Please let me know if I missed anything!

Comment: Oh, BTW,  obviously you can directly call `condition(true_body, false_body, current_continuation)`, completely omitting `if_cps`, but this makes it clearer in my head at least.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are over-attributing things to CPS.  First, CPS lets you *model* exceptions, generators, and functional calls, but it doesn't create them.  For example, modeling exceptions with CPS only gives me exception-like behavior in code that is itself in CPS.  I can, of course, use CPS as an implementation mechanism, an intermediate language, for exceptions or generators.  Compare this to a language with first-class continuations, e.g. Scheme's `call-with-current-continuation`.  With *that*, I could implement exceptions as a library.

Second, recursion gives you loops, not CPS.  If you had a language which couldn't express recursion nor had built-in loops, CPS transforming would clearly not change this.  You also don't need CPS to express loops as recursion, though it may be useful for things like `break` and `continue`.

To address your specific question, in some sense `if` is part of the definition of booleans.  If you want to do anything non-trivial with a boolean, you must at some point use `if`.  You could choose a different, non-abstract representation of booleans via their Church encoding, but converting the "native" booleans to this representation would require `if`, and at any rate this would just be word play.  While our `if-cps` would not require using `if` in this representation, this would only be because `if` is represented by the identity function in this representation.  Or to put it another way, we *are* using this representation's `if`.